Replacing hyperlink label with column content
Consider these two columns:

Is there a smart way to edit the hyperlink label "source" in the left column swapping it with content included in the right column?
I would like to obtain Intro.1, Intro.2 etc. as a hyperlink label without modifying the target and doing it manually

You can use the hyperlink function.
=HYPERLINK("url","link label [optional]")

Here is a link to the documentation for the function: Hyperlink
